# After I turned off my Laptop and then tried to turn it on the next day, Ubuntu doesn't boot correctly

Tags: boot, command-line, dual-boot, grub2

Everything worked just fine but after I wanted to turn on my Laptop (Dual-Boot) again Ubuntu is just showing me [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isa4N.jpg)

What can I do to fix it? Btw, I'm new to Ubuntu, that's my first problem.

Edit: fixed it

Comment: Does it it get stucked there only? You can try booting with the nomodeset parameter ( search the net for this ).

Comment: Yeah, when I try to get into Ubuntu, it just shows this. (I changed quite splash to nomodeset quite splash, didn't worked for me but now it shows a few different things on that black screen. But still the same screen)

Comment: Did you try, booting into recovery mode?